# Creating a self-updating score

Tags: python, pygame

I've checked a few others but their examples are a little different from what I'm trying to achieve. The goal is that everything the `player` shoots a `block`, the score will go up by ten. For me, the score stays at a constant 0 and does not update even if the `player` hits it's target. Here is what I have:

I am using `pygame.font.SysFont` because `pygame.freetype` was a little too confusing for me.

```
# Font
font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 16)

# Colours
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)

# Text
scoreValue = font.render("Score: " +str(score), True, black)
livesLeft = font.render("Health: " +str(health), True, black)

score = 0
health = 0

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    bullet_list.update()
    for bullet in bullet_list:
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(bullet, block_list, True)
        for block in block_hit_list:
            bullet_list.remove(bullet)
            sprite_list.remove(bullet)
            score += 10

    screen.fill(white)
    screen.blit(scoreValue, (4, 550))
    screen.blit(livesLeft, (4, 580))
    sprite_list.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

I shortened the code above to only show what I think it necessary, but if you need to see the full code, I will add it directly below this message. In this example, I have a `scoreValue` (ignore the health) but the `scoreValue` does not update on screen when the `player` hits one of the `blocks` on screen. Is there another way to track the score in pygame? Or am I just doing something wrong?

Here's the full code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([25, 25])
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.color = color
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def moveRight(self, pixels):
        if self.rect.x + pixels > 1000 - 50:
            self.rect.x = 1000 - 50
        self.rect.x += pixels

    def moveLeft(self, pixels):
        if self.rect.x - pixels < 0:
            self.rect.x = 0
        else:
            self.rect.x -= pixels

class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([25, 25])
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.color = color
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def update(self):
        self.rect.y +=5

class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([4,10])
        self.image.fill(blue)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def update(self):
        self.rect.y -=5

# Font
font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 16)

# Colours
red = (255, 0, 0)
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
blue = (0, 0, 255)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([800,600])

# Sprite Lists
sprite_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
block_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
bullet_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

# Player
player = Player(red)
player.rect.x = 375
player.rect.y = 500
sprite_list.add(player)

score = 0
health = 3

# Block
margin = 50
for column in range(4):
    for row in range(15):
        block = Block(black)
        block.rect.x = 30 + margin*row
        block.rect.y = 25 + margin*column
        block_list.add(block)
        sprite_list.add(block)

# Text
scoreValue = font.render("Score: " +str(score), True, black)
livesLeft = font.render("Health: " +str(health), True, black)

done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            bullet = Bullet()
            bullet.rect.x = player.rect.x + 12
            bullet.rect.y = player.rect.y
            sprite_list.add(bullet)
            bullet_list.add(bullet)

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] or keys[pygame.K_a]:
        player.moveLeft(3)
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] or keys[pygame.K_d]:
        player.moveRight(3)

    bullet_list.update()
    for bullet in bullet_list:
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(bullet, block_list, True)
        for block in block_hit_list:
            bullet_list.remove(bullet)
            sprite_list.remove(bullet)
            score += 10
            
        if bullet.rect.y < -10:
            bullet_list.remove(bullet)
            sprite_list.remove(bullet)
    
    
    screen.fill(white)
    screen.blit(scoreValue, (4, 550))
    screen.blit(livesLeft, (4, 580))
    sprite_list.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the value of the `score` does not magically update the `scoreValue` *Surface*. A [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) is just an image. You need to re-render the `scoreValue` *Surface* with the changed text:

```py
while not done:
    # [...]

    for bullet in bullet_list:
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(bullet, block_list, True)
        for block in block_hit_list:
            bullet_list.remove(bullet)
            sprite_list.remove(bullet)
            score += 10
            scoreValue = font.render("Score: " + str(score), True, black)
```